# Calling a function before it's defined | PHP

Tags: php

Is there any possible way when in **one** file - please note, just one file. To call a function when it isn't defined yet, e.g.

```
<?php

echo global_title();

function global_title()
{
    $title = $_GET['name'];

    return $title;
}

?>
```

I don't know how to explain this, but it's not quite possible isn't it? What about variable from another file (without including it) can be called in a different file, e.g.

**config.php**

```
<?php

$db = "localhost";

?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

// I do not want it to be accessed by including it or using sessions

echo $db;

?>
```

Know what I mean? :)

Comment: have you tried your code yet?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can call a function which is defined after calling it. That's because PHP first parses the file and then executes it.

As for the variable - this is not possible, you have to include the file.

Comment: Well, functions that are not enclosed in a conditional (like an `if`) are available after compilation of that file.  Variables are only available after execution reaches that line...

Comment: @ircmaxell interesting note, why would somebody define a function inside an if statement? Wouldn't it be better to evaluate whatever the if statement is evaluating inside the function?

Comment: @DougMolineux, Read up on conditional compilation. Basically, if it's unnecessary to process the function, don't.

Comment: Ah I see, so at the cost of a few milliseconds (more likely microseconds) you can sacrifice readability and maintainability. Job security! Yay

Comment: @DougMolineux the use case Pacerier is most widely seen when implementing code which could run on/together with older versions of other software. E.g. Check if php is lower version than 5.3.0 and add some function which is not included in the earlier versions or has different behavior. This doesn't sacrifice readability or maintainability. It provides compatibility.

Comment: You would definitely have a function definition in an if condition, when you don't want to redefine an already defined function, since this would result in PHP parsing error. Like so `if (!function_exists("my_function")) function my_function() {return "You see? :)";}`. And in this case you cannot call the function before it's definition.

Answer (score 7):

I just discovered that you can call a function if it's defined later in the same file.
But if it's defined in an other file, you must include the file before calling the function.

```
my_func();
function my_func() {...}
--->   No problem
```

but

```
my_func();
include_once 'define_my_func.php';
--->   PHP Fatal error
```

It's like a conditional function as in the example 2 on the doc on [user-defined functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call undefined function, it will raise a fatal error.
although in procedural code it can be called and afterwards defined. As the script is first parsed then executed.
includes don't matter, they behave as if they were written in the exact file.

there's no such thing as a variable "from a file". if the code defines the variable is not run, it can't be there.