# make function visible to switch statement

Tags: php, scope

I have a function in PHP that looks basically like this

```
$to_echo = prepare(2);
echo $to_echo;

function prepare($id){

    switch($id){
        case 1:
        $res = format1();
            break;
        case 2:
        $res = format2();
            break;
    }

    function format1(){
        return "asdf";
    }

    function format2(){
        return "1234";
    }

    return $res;

}
```

But I'm getting the error `Fatal error: Call to undefined function format2() in line...`

Can somehow the `$res` within the switch statement not see the function `format1` and `format2`? How can I give it access to that function?

[It works like this in javascript](http://jsbin.com/onuxaf/1/edit), but there's a lot to PHP I don't understand, so maybe this isn't the problem at all;

Comment: Related question: [Calling a function before it's defined](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3559875/1409082)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you try like this :

```
$to_echo = prepare(2);
echo $to_echo;

function prepare($id){
switch($id){
    case 1:
    $res = format1();
    return $res;
    break;
    case 2:
    $res = format2();
    return $res;
    break;
}

}

function format1(){
    return "asdf";
}

function format2(){
    return "1234";
}
```

Comment: This works. But how can the inside of the switch statement have access to functions on the exterior of its parent, when not even to the children of its parent? ^^ Thanks!

Comment: You can access all the functions which are written on a page or if you are including any file and you have any functions on it then you can access that as well inside of switch case.

Answer (score 2):

The nested functions `format1()` and `format2()` are not `declared` until a call to function prepare(...) has been made. However in the current sequence the declaration of these functions happens after the `switch-statement`. Therefore they are not present on time.

You should either try putting these function declarations at the top of the prepare(...) function or don't use nesting at all. I would recommend the latter.

Answer (score 1):

The thing with your code is that the functions (when within a function) needs to be declared **before** used:

```
function prepare($id){
  function format1(){..}
  function format2(){..}
  //do prepare here
  switch($id){..}
}
```

However, if you declare the functions outside of the function, they can come before or after the function.

```
function format1(){..}
function prepare($id){..}
function format2(){..}
```

Comment: yes, if you move the two inner functions above the switch, it will work