# PHP: Call to undefined function echocsv()

Tags: php, mysql, fatal-error

I am trying to run the following code

```
$query = sprintf('SELECT * FROM custfail');
$result = mysql_query($query, $conn) or die(mysql_error($conn));

/*
 * send response headers to the browser
 * following headers instruct the browser to treat the data as a csv file called export.csv
 */

header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=custfail.csv');

/*
 * output header row (if atleast one row exists)
 */

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if ($row) {
    echocsv(array_keys($row));
}

/*
 * output data rows (if atleast one row exists)
 */

while ($row) {
    echocsv($row);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
}

/*
 * echo the input array as csv data maintaining consistency with most CSV implementations
 * - uses double-quotes as enclosure when necessary
 * - uses double double-quotes to escape double-quotes 
 * - uses CRLF as a line separator
 */

function echocsv($fields)
{
    $separator = '';
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        if (preg_match('/\\r|\\n|,|"/', $field)) {
            $field = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $field) . '"';
        }
        echo $separator . $field;
        $separator = ',';
    }
    echo "\r\n";
```

When I run the code i get a CSV file with the following error located in it

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined function echocsv() in <b>*snip*</b> on line <b>31</b><br />
```

The line number is unrelated to the code posted as I have removed some previous code (a password check if statement(that this code is embedded in) and SQL connection details) but it is happening when calling this function,

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if ($row) {
    echocsv(array_keys($row));
}
```

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction

Comment: try to move your function to top of the page

Comment: Missing `}` after the end of the function is probably the issue.. although I would have expected PHP to throw a parse error if that was the actual code you used.

Comment: @RamSharma no it isn't - there's closing tags for the `if` and `foreach`, not for the function itself.

Comment: The function needs to be before the call, PHP executes it's script top to bottom.

Comment: @ɴᴀᴛʜ I agree, if functions is not closed than error would be parse error. In this case he has to move his function top of his page

Comment: The location of the function in a script doesn't matter, unless it is included from a php file after the call.  There is not enough information in this snip to determine the problem.  As is, this error should not be occurring

Comment: I have commented out all my password check if statement to rule that out and the issue still exists so now the code is effectively at the top of the page

Comment: Edited the failing section as forgot to include the }. But still the same issue

Comment: @RamSharma just tryed moving function to top of page and is now working.

Comment: @Darrell Very nice, now keep it mind when you access the function on same page than you should declare it first.

Comment: @Flosculus see his code is working after moving his code. PHP code is intemperate line by line so you have to take care of this

Comment: @RamSharma Every version of PHP I've used didn't care about this.  I'm interested to know what version/configuration he is using. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559875/calling-a-function-before-its-defined-php

Comment: @Flosculus if you declare function at bottom and access it on top of the page than it should not work in any version but you can ask Darrell about it

Comment: @Flosculus PHP 5.5 hosted on a 1&1 hosted server

Comment: @Flosculus if you accessing function on top of the page and you defined any function at bottom of page but you have some error between declare and define of function than you may face this kind of issue

Comment: @RamSharma The function in OP example was not conditionally defined, both call and definition are in the global (relative to the file) scope.  And there were no parse errors.  Tested it, I 'm pretty sure that when he placed the function at the top, it fixed the issue in a way we didn't expect, since we haven't seen the whole picture of his script.

Comment: @Flosculus all that was above the script was a commented out if statement and my connection details

Comment: @Flosculus I agree with you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of @RamSharma in his comments on the question. the issue was that I had the function at the bottom of the page, after it was being called

The solution was to move the function to lines above the call

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a "raw" *.php script, you need to define the function before the call, base on the reading here: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

> "Functions need not be defined before they are referenced, except when a function is conditionally defined(...)"

Comment: Functions need **not** be defined before they are referenced.

Comment: @Ja͢ck is right, my mistake, the issue had to do with the function being misplaced though anyway, since we're missing code in the question.