# PHP Calling a function within a static method of a class

Tags: php

```
class MainClass {

    public static function myStaticMethod(){
        return myFunction();

        function myFunction(){
            echo 'hello';
        }
    }
}
```

The above code when executed returns call to undefined function `myFunction();`

Please, any ideas on how to call the function within the method?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe you should define the function before calling the function. Also, I don't understand why you would need to create a global function like that within a class, What are you hoping to do?

Comment: @Scuzzy I dont think that's the problem here. You [can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559875/calling-a-function-before-its-defined-php) call it before it's defined.

Comment: Yes but not when nested within a class other function.

Comment: In this case I'd say the problem is that the method returns and execution is halted; therefore the function is never declared -- as you've explained in your answer.

Comment: Any particular reason why you define the function inside of your static method? Because if you do so, it will be usable in this method ONLY which makes the use of the function obsolete - you can just use its body.

Comment: @Pilan the function will be added to the global scope, meaning it can be used outside of the class, but the static method needs to be called to register the function in the first place, and will raise `Cannot redeclare myFunction()` on second call unless accounted for. Either way I still have no idea what the use case for defining a function like this is from @iamPacMan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the function deceleration to before you attempt to use it when defining functions within other functions...

```
class MainClass
{
  public static function myStaticMethod()
  {
    function myFunction()
    {
      echo 'hello';
    }
    return myFunction();
  }
}

MainClass::myStaticMethod(); // No error thrown
```

Note that repeat calls to MainClass::myStaticMethod will raise `Cannot redeclare myFunction()` unless you manage that.

Otherwise, move it outside of your class

```
function myFunction()
{
  echo 'hello';
}

class MainClass
{
  public static function myStaticMethod()
  {
    return myFunction();
  }
}
```

Comment: you are right. After creating the function before calling it, it works but there was an error. Which I think made calling it before declared raised the error call to undefined function

Comment: There variables declared in the static method which I wanted to use them in the function but It raises an error undefined variable. So I guess the variables are not able to be parsed into the function from the method

Comment: You can wrap it with http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php but really I think your implementation needs review.

Comment: Yes I declared it global because Its within a controller and I'll be calling it from other controllers and models

Comment: A `public static function` can be called from anywhere as well, just like your existing `MainClass::myStaticMethod()` method can be.